# Reporting Services Timeout with Range Chart (Gantt)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I have a chart report using a range chart with SSRS 2012.  It was working great until last week.  Now, it won't finish running in the IDE or on the report server.  I get rsInternalError, and when I look at the log files I get a ReportServerStorageException which to me indicates timeout or another problem from SQL Server.

"An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database."

However, the query is lightning fast and I am aware of slow parameter queries and the param sniffing problem.  I've confirmed that is now what is happening here though.

If I change the report so that it groups on a field that will only show maybe 10 or 20 rows, then it works fine.  When the row series is grouped on a field which returns 100 to 200+ rows then that's where it fails, but only in some cases.  It seems a difference of one or two rows being returned makes the difference between working and failing.

In either case, the SQL Command to the database would be the exact same.  The only difference is on the report rendering side as there would be more rows on the y axis.

Anyone have any idea what's happening here?  I don't understand why it's failing on the SQL Side.  It also shouldn't be failing on the rendering side.

Comment: Do you have any aggregate functions in the report? How many records are returned from the query?

Comment: No aggregate functions.  When I created it last week it worked fine and was super fast.  Then a couple days later it wouldn't work by default which was 'all of time - no filter'.  If I filtered up until 2 days earlier it worked fine, but when I included anything after that date it failed.  Now, on a smaller recordset I see the same behaviour if I introduce a TOP X in the query.  Anything up to TOP 55 works fine and is lightning fast.  Once I have SELECT TOP 58, or TOP 60 the report fails to generate as before.  The query runs by itself lightning fast in each scenario in SQL.

Comment: I discovered something tonight.  In my query I have Min(Timestamp) and Max(Timestamp).  If I hardcode the dates here it runs fine, otherwise it will never finish executing when trying to render the report.  In SQL the query speed is the same with or without the aggregate.  Very weird.

Comment: Further research shows that the problem wasn't with Min or Max(Timestamp).  In the Range chat I specified a Maximum value Interval for the Horizontal axis instead of using the default 'Auto'.  The problem with auto is that it always adds a buffer of space of a few weeks out to the chart.  Though, if I manually set any value less than about 10 days out (let's say DateTime.Now or Now + 5 days) the report rendering will timeout.  I am certain this is some kind of bug in Reporting Services.

Comment: Strange. Thanks for reporting back.